# Size mismatch error when installing opencv2 on a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3

I'm trying to install opencv2 with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

When I use the above statement, during installation of opencv2 on Linux I get a "size mismatch error" and it is not installed.

How can I resolve this error on my Pi 3?

Comment: Could you please [edit] to include the full error or stack trace you are receiving? It's difficult to understand exactly what went wrong without the *full* error message. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Please follow Auroras advice and edit your question accordingly. Thanks!